# Skip rows in a Select statement in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement to skip 'N'records and take next 'M' records in a Select statement in Teradata. I could not figure out how to implement skip 'N' records in Teradata. Can someone here pls guide me? In MySQL, I can do the same with LIMIT N,M. I'm looking for something similar in teradata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize Standard SQL ROW_NUMBER plus Teradata's QUALIFY:

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) BETWEEN N and N+M
```